# Core Data - Count of Related Records

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am new to Core Data programming and am trying to work out the concepts involved.  I have an object called a `Lease` that has a many-to-many relationship with `Apartment` objects.  Given a `Lease` object, how do I get a count of the related `Apartment` objects or an NSArray of the related objects?

Thank you!

~~Garth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple different ways:

1. Using the generated Core Data accessor:

   ```
   NSSet * apartments = [myLease apartments];
   NSUInteger numberOfApartments = [apartments count];
   ```
2. Using KeyPaths:

   ```
   NSSet * apartments = [myLease valueForKey:@"apartments"];
   NSUInteger numberOfApartments = [apartments valueForKey:@"@count"];
   ```
3. Using KVC (if your class is fully KVC-compliant):

   ```
   NSUInteger numberOfApartments = [myLease countOfApartments];
   ```
4. Using a fetch request:

   ```
   NSFetchRequest * r = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
   [r setEntity:apartmentEntityDescription];
   [r setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lease = %@", myLease]];
   NSArray * apartments = [myManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:r error:nil];
   NSUInteger numberOfApartments = [myManagedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:r error:nil];
   [r release];
   ```

Feel free to mix-and-match those lines.

Comment: What about sorting by `apartments.@count`?